# Manipulating the size of flexbox containers while shrinking window size

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have been trying to clone the Apple Store website using just CSS and HTML for practice. One problem I have to deal with is the shrinking of the flex containers I have used, while reducing the size of the webpage window. I'm also not sure how to reduce the image size to maintain certain (height X width) ratios. I have noticed that the apple website (https://www.apple.com/) uses 3 fixed image sizes to which the images shrink to, while reducing the size of the webpage. Can this be implemented using just CSS and HTML or does this require JavaScript?

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Apple Clone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="apple.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>  
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home"><img class="logo" src="homelogo.png" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Store">Store</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Mac">Mac</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#iPad">iPad</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="iPhone">iPhone</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Watch">Watch</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Vision">Vision</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#AirPods">AirPods</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#TV & Home">TV & Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Entertainment">Entertainment</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Accessories">Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Support">Support</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </nav>

    <a href="#MBA" class="mba">
        <div class="txt1">MacBook Air 15"</div>
        <div class="txt2">Impressively big. Impossibly thin.</div>
        <div class="txt3">Learn more ></div>
        <div><img class="mbapic" src="MBA.png" alt=""></div>
    </a>

    <a class="iphone14" href="#14">
        <div class="itxt1">iPhone 14</div>
        <div class="itxt2">Wonderfull.</div>
        <div class="itxt3">Learn more ></div>
        <div class="itxt4">Buy ></div>
        <div><img class="i14img" src="i14.png" alt=""></div>
    </a>
    <div class="flex_container">
        <a class="event" href="#event">
            <div><img class="eventimg" src="event.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="evtxt1">Apple Event</div>
            <div class="evtxt2">Watch online on 9/12 at 10 a.m. PT.</div>
            <div class="evtxt3">Learn more ></div>
        </a>
        <a class="pro14" href="#pro14">
            <div class="pro14txt1">iPhone 14 Pro</div>
            <div class="pro14txt2">Pro. Beyond.</div>
            <div class="pro14txt3">Learn more ></div>
            <div><img  class="propic" src="pro14.png" alt=""></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <a class="ipad" href="">
            <div class="padtxt1">iPad Pro</div>
            <div class="padcont">
                <div class="padtxt2">Supercharged by</div>
                <div><img class="m2img" src="m2.png" alt=""></div>
            </div>
            <div class="padtxt3">Learn more ></div>
            <div class="padtxt4">Buy ></div>
            <div><img class="padimg" src="padpro.png" alt=""></div>
        </a>
        <a class="watch" href="">
            <div class="watchcont">
                <div><img class="wlogo" src="wlogo.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="wtxt1">WATCH</div>
            </div>
            <div class="wtxt2">SERIES 8</div>
            <div class="wtxt3">A healthy leap ahead.</div>
            <div class="wtxt4">Learn more ></div>
            <div class="wtxt5">Buy ></div>
            <div><img class="wimg" src="watch.png" alt=""></div>
        </a> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background-color: white;
}
nav{
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
nav ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 45px;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 33px;
}

li .navtxt{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
li .logo{
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
}

/* .mba is the flexbox container for the macbook air part */
.mba{
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 45px;
    height: 685px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: top;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.mba .mbapic{
    height: 225px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
.mba .txt1{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 45px;
    color: black;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight: 500;

}

.mba .txt2{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.mba .txt3{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

/* .iphone14 is the lfex container for the iphone14 block */
.iphone14{
    display: flex;
    height: 685px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
    margin-top: 12px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: top;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.iphone14 .itxt1{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 45px;
    color: black;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight: 500;

}
.iphone14 .itxt2{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
.iphone14 .itxt3{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
.iphone14 .i14img{
    width: 910px;
    height: 410px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
.iphone14 .itxt4{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 12px;
    display: inline;
}

.mba .txt3:hover,.iphone14 .itxt4:hover,.iphone14 .itxt3:hover,.pro14 .pro14txt3:hover, .event .evtxt3:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* this is the parent flex container for the event flexbox and the 14pro flex container. I have used nested so that i can display the flex containers side by side  */
.flex_container{
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 612px;
    gap: 12px;

}
.event{
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 12px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    width: 49%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.event .eventimg{
    height: 375px;
    max-width: 358px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 45px;
}
.event .evtxt1{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 525;
}
.event .evtxt2{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.event .evtxt3{
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 13px;
    font-weight: 250;
}

/* flex container for the iphone14 pro block */
.pro14{
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 12px;
    height: 600px;
    width: 49%;

    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.pro14 .propic{
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 455px;

    width: 100%;

}
.pro14 .pro14txt1{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 525;

}
.pro14 .pro14txt2{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.pro14 .pro14txt3{
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 13px;
    font-weight: 250;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/* second parent flexbox container for the ipad and watch blocks */
.container2{
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 612px;
}
.ipad{
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 12px;
    height: 600px;
    width: 49%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.watch{
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 12px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    width: 49%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
.padcont{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 30px;
    width: 49%;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.m2img{
    height: 42px;
    width: 42px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 7px;
}
.padtxt2{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.padtxt1{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 525;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.padtxt3{
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 250;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.padtxt4{
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 250;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.padimg{
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.watchcont{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.wtxt1{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.wlogo{
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
.wtxt2{
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.85);
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.wtxt3{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;

}
.wtxt4{
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 250;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.wtxt5{
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 250;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}
.wimg{
    height: 325px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
.wtxt4:hover,.wtxt5:hover,.padtxt3:hover,.padtxt4:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```